# "The process cannot access the file because it is used by another process" on editor called with php tmpfile()

Tags: php, windows

I have a PHP program which calls `tmpfile()`, populate it with content, call an external editor with that file such that the user can modify the content, and after closing the editor the program will process the modified content.

It works well on Linux but on Windows, the editor says "The process cannot access the file because it is used by another process" if I want to save the file.

The PHP is similar to the below:

```
$file = tmpfile();
fwrite($file, 'some initial content');
$path = stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri'];
system("notepad $path");
// process the file afterwards
```

How can I modify the PHP script such that I can modify the file?

Comment: fclose() before the system call?

Comment: fclose() will remove the tmpfile() as stated in php doc